# Twitter Boostrap - getting alert message to stick to the top of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to get [bootstrap's alerts](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#alerts) messages to stick to the top like the navbar component but no success.

First, the context:
I'm sending an ajax request through jQuery and then process the response. This part of the idea is complete. All I need to do now is to know how to make an alert message appear at the top of the page **right under the navbar** that is fixed to the top thanks to bootstrap's navbars. I've tried many things with the affix classes but still can't do it.

Here's where I try to create a `div` element behaving like the alert message:

```
success:function(msg) {
    if (msg == "fail") {
        $('body').append('<div class="alert alert-error affix-top"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>Error !</strong> You can\'t specify a closed status if status is not set as "closed"</div>');
    }
}
```

So I know for sure this works since the alert message is added but... at the bottom of the page. I want it to be like 5 pixels under the navbar component but can't make this work.

**Any idea what I need to set to make this work?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an element inserted *before* all other elements use [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/). this inserts the object as the first child instead of as the last like `.append()`:

```
success:function(msg) {
    if (msg == "fail") {
        $('body').prepend('<div class="alert alert-error affix-top">...</div>');
    }
}
```

that gets it at the top of the page, then it'll be up to you to make sure it's where you want it thereafter.

Also, I would also look at either using a templating system or build your object using jQuery and avoid long string insertions (though I suppose this may be personal preference).

Comment: It's kind of a work around but I don't simply want it to be before all the rest. I want that kind of "floating" state where it will just be displayed at this place without specifically being at this place in the DOM. See what I mean?

Comment: @MichaelDeKeyser: then you probably want to use absolute positioning and play with the z-index. (something like [this](http://tympanus.net/Development/jbar/) you mean?)

Comment: @MichaelDeKeyser: I'm not 1005 fluent in bootstrap, but you can take a look at the [stylesheet](http://tympanus.net/Development/jbar/css/style.css) of that example and see how they setup the CSS to make it fixed to the top.

Answer (score 3):

You should append it but to the navbar element.

```
success:function(msg) {
    if (msg == "fail") {
        $('.navbar').append('<div class="alert alert-error affix-top"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>Error !</strong> You can\'t specify a closed status if status is not set as "closed"</div>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a div before the nav bar

```html
<body>
    <div class="alert alert-success navbar-fixed-top" style="display:none; z-index:9999999999" id="dvmsg" role="alert">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-6">
                Success
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
...
```

then from the JS you can call 
 $("#dvmsg").fadeIn().fadeOut(1000);